# query related to the res/ xml folder while generating an app containing simple preference app

Tags: sharedpreferences, preferences

from last 1 months i've started working on android, now on preferences. can any1 pls let me know, whether we have to create an xml folder for writing preferences in our app, because as i was refering on few sites, it was mentioned to create file in res/xml folder.

Thanx in advance..

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to say??

Comment: Thanks Segi for replying back.. This issue has been solved..

Comment: :P ohhkk.. i just see and asked.. okey. good..

Comment: Tenx.. issue has been solved before 8 months